# Ext4 fast_commit feature

Tags: filesystem, ext4

Since 5.10 kernel there is a new feature called ***fast_commit***. In arch wiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ext4 you can read that it can be enabled in existing filesystem with:

`tune2fs -O fast_commit /dev/drivepartition`

but in https://lwn.net/Articles/842385/ there is:

> Fast commits are activated at filesystem creation time, so users will
> have to recreate their filesystems to use this feature.

So is `tune2fs -O fast_commit` truly enable this feature in existing filesystem ?

Answer (score 1):

This needs a straight answer.

Edit: I stand corrected, this capability was added to tune2fs later. It creates the fast_commit journal just like "mke2fs -O fast_commit" would at creation time.

Check your filesystem features with "tune2fs -l /dev/whatever" and if fast commits are enabled, it will show up in the features line.

Comment: What about this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/679006/ext4-fast-commit-feature ?

Comment: Thanks for that, I started to doubt what I said later as well but at the time it was what I thought I had pieced together from vague, outdated info. I often get frustrated to find unanswered questions when searching for the same info.